# Using the session option in Nextjs API routes

Tags: session, next.js, amazon-dynamodb, next-auth

Been stuck on this for the entire day, can't figure out how to get the session object in the API routes in `Next.js v13.4.1` & `next-auth 4.22.1`

## **Is there any way to be able to use the session in the API backend routes?**

Details:

### Front-end

The session seems to be available on the website

```
import { signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
...
const { data: session } = useSession();
//Now we can use the session successfully after the user signs-in
```

### [...nextauth].js

Here is the setup:

```
export const authOptions = {
   debug: true,
   session: {
     strategy: "jwt"
   },
   providers: [
     TwitterProvider({
        clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
        version: "2.0", // opt-in to Twitter OAuth 2.0
     })
   ],
   adapter: DynamoDBAdapter(
     client, {tableName: "leaderboard-auth"}
   )}
```

*PS1: I've tested with an explicit session strategy & without, same result.*
*PS2: I implemented a db session strategy because the session was not retrievable in API routes. I thought that the session should be persisted.*
*PS3: The DynamoDB adapter seems to work:*
[image]

### API Routes

I've tested multiple ways to get the session:

#### 1. Using `getServerSession`

The session is still `null` even after the user signs in.

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from '../auth/[...nextauth]'
...
...
export default async function handler(req, res) {
   const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
   console.log(session ); // session is always null
}
```

#### 2. Using `getSessionAndUser`

The session is still `null` even after the user signs in.

```
import { authOptions } from '../auth/[...nextauth]'
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt"
...
...
export default async function handler(req, res) {
   const token = await getToken({req});
   const session = await authOptions.adapter.getSessionAndUser(token)
   console.log(session ); // session is always null
}
```

#### 3. Checking `cookies` & `rawHeaders`

I don't know if its normal, but the request's cookies is empty & headers don't contain the jwt token.

```
...
...
export default async function handler(req, res) {
   console.log('cookies', req.cookies); // result is always {}
   console.log('headers', req.rawHeaders ); // no relevant cookies! 
}
```